# Javascript - get image alt text of clicked link for Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to use the Javascript below capturing the alt attribute of an image when user click on it, but the result I can get is always null. I want to extract the "Youtube" alt attribute.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" title="Youtube" target="_blank">
<img src="/example" class="example" alt="Youtube">
</a>
```

```
function() {
    var elem = {{element}},
        attr = "alt", // change to corresponding attributes
            result = (elem.getAttribute && elem.getAttribute(attr)) || null;

    if( !result ) {
        var attrs = elem.attributes,
            l = attrs.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if(attrs[i].nodeName === attr)
                result = attrs[i].nodeValue;
                }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is `{{element}}`? Is that not producing an error? And why so many lines for just getting an `alt` attribute?

Comment: {{element}} is a default expression in Google Tag Manager to identify the element clicked. As I want to track all the images click within the page, seems using Javascript is easier.

Comment: Perhaps try using the gtm.linkClick auto-event listener to create a dataLayer variable that can access the "alt" attribute (not sure if I'm using correct nomenclature). For example when you click the link, the gtm.linkClick should capture the element properties (which is how you get the {{element}} macros). Your new dataLayer variable could be called {{element alt}} = gtm.element.children[0].alt, or something like that. Perhaps someone can verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the JS code you posted above is a GTM JS macro? I'm not sure if you have a click listener or a link click listener, but if it's the second, it's bound not to work because alt is an attribute of the image and not the link. In case you have a link click listener, this JS GTM macro might just work:

```
function(){
    var self = {{element}};
    if (typeof self.children === 'undefined' || self.children.lenght == 0 || typeof self.children[0].alt === 'undefined')
    {
    return '';
    }
    return self.children[0].alt;
}
```

You could also adjust your own code to take the attribute from the child `img`.