# Capturing link alt via Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I read [Javascript - get image alt text of clicked link for Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528991/javascript-get-image-alt-text-of-clicked-link-for-google-tag-manager)

is it possible to track alt of clicked link?

I tried to do this via DOM element but fail. Is it posible to do this without JS?

Answer (score 2):

Untested and from the top of my head, but this should work like in the screenshot below (returns the alt text of any clicked element, not only links).

[image]